# center Text with flex and float button at right end

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

need two div at center vertically and horizontally too,
button and heading at center, like this,
[image]

my tried code is here,

```
        <div style={{height:'100px', backgroundColor:'grey'}}>
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-md-center align-items-center h-100">
                <div >
                    <h1 style={{color:'#EEEEEE'}}>INNOVATE WITH </h1>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div className="" style={{float:'right'}}>
                <Button style={{width:'200px'}} className='float-right'>Get Started</Button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

which is showing like this,
[image]

when i try to do this,

```
        <div style={{height:'100px', backgroundColor:'grey'}}>
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-md-center align-items-center h-100">
                <div >
                    <h1 style={{color:'#EEEEEE'}}>INNOVATE WITH</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="" style={{float:'right'}}>
                    <Button style={{width:'200px'}} className='float-right'>Get Started</Button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

it will be [image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `justify-content-md-center` use  `justify-content-between`

and for `h1` use `text-center` and `w-100` bootstrap classes to align it center.

```
<h1 className="text-center w-100" style={{color:'#EEEEEE'}}>INNOVATE WITH</h1>
```

Comment: Why are you using custom CSS when the OP is using BS?